# Show a matrix is invertible

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

How to show that 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1233&2344&1324&3456\\ 2342&11233&1432&13256\\234132&32432&1234567&43254\\423412&42354&452356&13245\end{pmatrix}$$
is invertible ? I could compute the determinant, but it's very very long...

Comment: @SamiBen: Oh, true, I had already seen this link long times ago, but I had totally forgot the way to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you take the coefficients modulo 2, you see that there is only $1$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. Therefore $$\det A\equiv 1\pmod 2,$$
and thus $\det A$ is odd. Therefore $\det A\neq 0$ and thus $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Very nice trick!

Comment: sweet. I would give 10 upvotes if I could.

Comment: @Surb: Thanks for the trick :-)